# change log file name at every run

Tags: python, logging

I have a following `python` logging configuration file which

```
[loggers]
keys=root,paramiko

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter,fileFormatter

[logger_paramiko]
level=CRITICAL
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=paramiko

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('run.log', 'w')

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s] %(message)s

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=[%(asctime)s - %(pathname)s:%(lineno)s - %(levelname)s] %(message)s
```

As you can see I'm logging to console and to file. The name of the file is `run.log`. I want to be able to append/prepend to the file name a timestamp, i.e. name my log file as `2019-08-08__18:13:40-run.log`.  I searched online, but couldn't find anything. How can I do it through a configuration file?

Comment: What is a "run"? Also, have you tried [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#module-level-functions) to specify the log file name?

Comment: @mustaccio I need ability to specify file name from the configuration file, not from actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The way that python reads the `args` key from the config is to run it through `eval()` so you can put any valid code there. You can put pretty much anything you want there, something that is very likely different on every run would be this:

```
args=(str(time.time())+'.log', 'w') # needs import time in the code
args=(str(hash(' '))+'.log', 'w') # works without import, 99% chance to be unique
```